# Setting the position of an image python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have added the image with the relevant code. My challenge is setting a desired position of the image. The default position is the center of the canvas, how do I change that, please help.
Thank you

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded some *.gif image as the turtle's image, you can then `turtle.goto()` (or `turtle.setposition()`, etc.) where ever you want on the canvas and `turtle.stamp()` the image to leave it behind:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# https://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/10757/1075705.gif

SQUIRREL_IMAGE = '1075705.gif'

screen = Screen()

screen.register_shape(SQUIRREL_IMAGE)

turtle = Turtle(shape=SQUIRREL_IMAGE)
turtle.penup()

turtle.goto(100, 100)
turtle.stamp()
turtle.goto(-100, -100)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]